# PHP echo data - append to html element

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, svg

I'm storing some html elements (or actualy <**rect**> svg elements) in a database as strings.

I have a PHP that echoes back the data:

```
$db = getConnection();
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT `copy` FROM `draggable`');
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$numberOfElements = count($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfElements; $i++) {
    echo $result[$i]['copy'];
}
$statement->closeCursor();
```

The echoed result in the browser response is:

```
<rect class="draggable" x="385.53125" y="139" width="50" height="50" style="fill: rgb(0, 128, 0); fill-opacity: 0.2; position: relative; left: -445.46875px; top: 13px;" id="TmOZB"></rect>
<rect class="draggable" x="140.53125" y="276" width="50" height="50" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 255); fill-opacity: 0.2; position: relative; left: -710.46875px; top: 148px;" id="wQXtQ"></rect>
<rect class="draggable" x="293.53125" y="99" width="50" height="50" style="fill: rgb(255, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 0.2; position: relative; left: -548.46875px; top: -28px;" id="atlxR"></rect>
<rect class="draggable" x="73.53125" y="136" width="50" height="50" style="fill: rgb(0, 128, 0); fill-opacity: 0.2; position: relative; left: -762.46875px; top: 18px;" id="fLuJl"></rect>
```

Now I would like to get that result via Ajax and append it to a svg element (with the id **#mapa**). This is what I have so far:

```
$('#mapa').append($.post('./getElements'));
```

But it doesn't work. What should I change?

Comment: what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I would like to see the echoed elements put inside the svg element #mapa, meaning to see them on the screen, which doesn't happen now.

Answer (score 2):

[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) returns [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR), not request's result. Also request is executed asynchoronously. So you can add request's result to element in `$.post` success callback:

```
$.post('./getElements', function(data) { $('#mapa').append(data); }));
```

Comment: It seems to be almost working, but it doesn't get appended as console.log returns the string with a lot of backslashes like: "<rect class=\"draggable\" x=\"67.53125\" y=\"274\" width=\"50\" .... ". I'm trying data.replace("\\",""); but it doesn't work, what should I use instead? (I know I have to remove the "" around as well).

Comment: @oneday take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rob2ewky/1/) handling replace.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your php file is getElements try this

```
$.post( "./getElements", function( data ) {
   $('#mapa').append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $.post("./getElements", dataType:"html", function( data ) {
    $('#mapa').html(data);
    // or
    $('#mapa').append(data); // (your case)
    });
```

Check the request URL (./getElements), if it's right to return HTML Data.